# how to pass variable from one function to another in same controller

Tags: codeigniter

I want to pass a variable from one function to another function , both are in same controller, I am using Codeigniter, my controller code is

```
public function passes() {
    $this->question();
    $this->load->view('passes', $data);
}

public function question() {
    if ($this->input->post('slug')) {
        $slug = $_POST['slug'];
        $slug = $this->Welcome_model->selectid($slug);
        $passcat_id = $slug[0]->id;
        log_message('error', 'collected id is ' . $passcat_id);
        $data['question'] = $this->Welcome_model->selectquestion($passcat_id);
    }
}
```

here is my code I want to print data $data['question']in view page .

Thank you.

Comment: what about set session ? for example , $this->session->set_userdata('passcat_id',$passcat_id); and then call the session $pass = $this->session->userdata('passcat_id'); ...

Comment: `$data = $this->data_from_other_function();`
this worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your code as following solution.

```
    public function passes() {
        $data = $this->question();
        $this->load->view('passes', $data);
    }

    public function question() {
        $data = array();
        if ($this->input->post('slug')) {
            $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
            $slug = $this->Welcome_model->selectid($slug);
            $passcat_id = $slug[0]->id;
            log_message('error', 'collected id is ' . $passcat_id);
            $data['question'] = $this->Welcome_model->selectquestion($passcat_id);
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

I hope this will helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public function passes(){
    $data = $this->question();
    $this->load->view('passes',$data);
}

public function question()
{
if($this->input->post('slug')) {
        $slug = $this->input->post('slug');
        $slug = $this->Welcome_model->selectid($slug);
        $passcat_id = $slug[0]['id'];
        log_message('error', 'collected id is ' . $passcat_id);
        $data['question']= $this->Welcome_model->selectquestion($passcat_id);
         return $data;
}
}
```

I hope this will helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
public function question($input)
{
     if(!emtpy($input) {
        $slug = $input;
        $slug = $this->Welcome_model->selectid($slug);
        $passcat_id = $slug[0]->id;
        log_message('error', 'collected id is ' . $passcat_id);
        $data['question']= $this->Welcome_model->selectquestion($passcat_id);
        return $data['question'];
     }

}
public function passes(){
     $this->question($_POST['input']);
     $this->load->view('passes',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `flashdata` and `redirect` for this

```php
public function passes()
{
    // 3.) Get your question
    $question = $this->session->flashdata('item');
    // 4.) Pass to view
    $this->load->view('passes', ['question' => $question]);
}

public function question()
{
    if ($this->input->post('slug')) {
        $slug = $_POST['slug'];
        $slug = $this->Welcome_model->selectid($slug);
        $passcat_id = $slug[0]->id;
        log_message('error', 'collected id is ' . $passcat_id);
        $question = $this->Welcome_model->selectquestion($passcat_id);

        // 1.) Store your data in flash data
        $this->session->set_flashdata('question', $question);
        // 2.) Redirect to your passes function
        redirect('/yourcontroller/passes');
    }
}
```